# VMWare networking mode (NAT)

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion, nat, bridge

I've created a new WinXP vitual machine on my win7 using VMware player. This virtual machine is using NAT `(10.0.0.0/24`) and has a WAMP server running. I want this to be NAT as I want the server to be running on a different subnet IP to my host pc (Win7). This is my virtual machines NAT settings:

```
Subnet Add - 10.0.0.0
Subnet Mask - 255.255.255.0
Gateway - 10.0.0.2
My VMware machine (Win XP with WAMP server) IP add - 10.0.0.128
Port Forwarding - 10.0.0.128:5000
```

My host pc IP is `(192.168.0.101/24)`. I want to be able to access the WAMP server on my virtual machine from my host pc? However, I can not ping my virtual machine IP from my host pc but I can ping my host pc IP from my virtual machine? I have also tried from my host pcs browser http://10.0.0.128:5000 but no luck. There is no firewall installed on the virtual machine just a WAMP server and I turned off firewall on my host pc but still cant ping my Virtual machines IP?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a Bridged adapter instead?

Comment: Yes I am doing experiment on SOP policy so I am trying to make two websites appear to be from two origins hence the two ip subnets (10.0.0.0 and 192.168.0.0)